# Can't make a query on a JSON by using AWS S3 Select

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I am trying to query a JSON object by using aws `s3-select`. My JSON array structure is like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "s3",
        "url": "https://...",
        "time": "2019-07-02",
        "summary": "by using s3 select..."
    },
    {
        "title": "athena",
        "url": "https://...",
        "time": "2019-07-01",
        "summary": "by using athena..."
    },
    {
        "title": "mysql",
        "url": "https://...",
        "time": "2019-06-30",
        "summary": "by using mysql..."
    }
]
```

All of the objects inside the array have the same property. Now I want to execute a query to return all objects whose title is equal to, let's say, `mysql` or `athena`.

I've tried a lot of different scripts in aws console but none of them worked.  It returns either an empty array/ object or gives an error. For example:

```
select * from s3object s where s[*].title = 'athena' //NOT WORKING.
select * from S3Object[*] s where s.title = 'athena' //NOT WORKING.
```

Is my JSON array structure wrong (since my objects don't have a key name)? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try it without the square brackets at the start and end of the file and without commas between records. See file examples in: [(50) How I used "Amazon S3 Select" to selectively query CSV/JSON data stored in S3. | LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-i-used-amazon-s3-select-query-selective-data-stored-sharma/)

Comment: I see, thanks @JohnRotenstein, maybe it will work, but this structure is the way that i need (which is the standard array of custom objects)

Comment: In that case, the file cannot be used with Amazon S3 Select.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should select the array at the root level.
So first `[*]` corresponds to root. Next `[*]` the top level array in root.

Try below query, it would work:

```
select * from S3Object[*][*] s where s.title = 'athena'
```

Comment: Good explanation @Manoj Kumar Vohra.

Comment: Wish this common use case was explained in their docs. Cheers!